# How to configure AWS IAM to enable a user to download some folders/prefixes from a bucket, but not others?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, bucket

We need to configure an IAM policy in Amazon Web Services to allow someone to use the CLI (command line interface) to download objects from certain folders/prefixed but not others. For example, if our bucket were called "companybucket", we have three folders/prefixes:

- companybucket/apples
- companybucket/oranges
- companybucket/bananas

We need the external user to be able to download objects in the "apples" and "bananas" folders but not the oranges.

So far, we have created the following IAM policy to get started with the "apples"

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetLifecycleConfiguration",
                "s3:GetBucketTagging",
                "s3:GetInventoryConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:GetBucketLogging",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetAccelerateConfiguration",
                "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionTorrent",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetEncryptionConfiguration",
                "s3:GetBucketObjectLockConfiguration",
                "s3:GetBucketRequestPayment",
                "s3:GetAccessPointPolicyStatus",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
                "s3:GetObjectTagging",
                "s3:GetMetricsConfiguration",
                "s3:GetBucketPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:GetBucketPolicyStatus",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:GetObjectRetention",
                "s3:GetBucketWebsite",
                "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
                "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                "s3:GetObjectLegalHold",
                "s3:GetBucketNotification",
                "s3:GetReplicationConfiguration",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectTorrent",
                "s3:DescribeJob",
                "s3:GetBucketCORS",
                "s3:GetAnalyticsConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionForReplication",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:GetAccessPointPolicy",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::companybucket/apples",
                "arn:aws:s3:::companybucket/apples/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetAccessPoint",
                "s3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:ListAccessPoints",
                "s3:ListJobs",
                "s3:HeadBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then, in the AWS console UI website, we have gone to IAM (Identify & Access Management) >> Users >> chosen the user in question >> permissions tab >> directly attached the policy to the user

Then, the user executes the following command in CLI:

```
aws s3 sync s3://companybucket/apples  MYFILES
```

The following error appears:  "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied"

What are we doing wrong?  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach has been successful for us to allow a AWS user set up in IAM the ability to download files/objects from some (but not all) folders in a bucket.

**FIRST**, set up the following policy in IAM.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowStatement01",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::companybucket"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "",
                        "apples",
                        "bananas"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowStatement02",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::companybucket"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "apples/*",
                        "bananas/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowStatement03",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::companybucket/apples/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::companybucket/bananas/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**SECOND**, attach the newly created policy directly to the user in IAM.

**THIRD**, tell the user to set up a root-level local folder called MYFILES and then enter the following command in CLI (command line interface):

```
aws s3 sync s3://companybucket/apples MYFILES
```